# Vgg16 and Resnet50 overfits despite including 100k images - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, vgg-net, overfitting-underfitting

I am training a classifier using vgg16 and Resnet50. The data I have collected contains 100k RGB images belonging to four classes, each containing ~25k (the unbalanced issue was minor and compensated by augmentations). The dimension of each image is 75x75 RGB.

I face overfitting early in training, around epoch 20 out of 100. While the final accuracy in four classes is above 70-80% for each class, the overfitting problem has raised a serious concern. Anyone can who can comment, I appreciate it very much.

Here is my code:

```
IMG_WIDTH=75
IMG_HEIGHT=75
input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3)

model_name='Classification_vgg16'
model_filename = (model_name+'.hdf5') # Model Filename Initialization 

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
loss=['categorical_crossentropy']
metrics = ['accuracy']

class1='A'
class2='B'
class3='C'
class4='D'

epochs = 100
batch_size = 32
target_size = (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)


 # Here is the vgg16 model loaded from tensorflow
base_model=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(
    include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None, pooling='max')


base_model.trainable = True

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3))

x = base_model(inputs)

# I am adding two FCN, the last layer takes care of classification, followed by softmax activation. Loss function used is categorical cross entropy.

x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

model=keras.Model(inputs, x)
model.summary()


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,  # this is the training directory
        target_size=target_size,  # all images will be resized to the target size
        color_mode='rgb',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical',
        interpolation='nearest',
        seed=42)




vaidation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
validation_generator = vaidation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_path,  # this is the validation directory
        target_size=target_size,  # all images will be resized to the target size
        color_mode='rgb',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical',
        interpolation='nearest',
        seed=42)


# Compiling and training the model

model.compile(optimizer, loss , metrics)

model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint((model_path+model_filename), monitor='val_loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True) # model_path directs to where the model is going to be saved

model.summary()


history = model.fit(
     train_generator,
     steps_per_epoch = num_of_train_img_raw//batch_size,
     epochs = epochs, 
     validation_data = validation_generator, # relates to the validation data.
     validation_steps = num_of_val_img_raw//batch_size,
     callbacks=[model_checkpoint],
     use_multiprocessing = False)
```

You can see from the image below that the model has classical overfitting.

[image]

The same issue holds true with Resnet50 (including training from scratch and partial freezing). I would genuinely appreciate your comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should augment your data -> e.g. add noise, crop, flip while training to increase your training data and make your network more robust. Since you are already using the [ImageDataGenerator()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) you can just add tags like vertical_flip=True -> ImageDataGenerator(vertical_flip=True) to allow your imageGenerator to flip the images sometimes to augment your data. See the link for more Augmentation tags.

Comment: Thanks @Finn Meyer for your answer. We can always add augmentation, such as rotation, scaling, brightness, etc when limited data is available. The data already leverages rotational augmentation conducted in the dataset (not on the fly while feeding the data via ImageDataGenerator). But that does not help avoid overfitting in this case, when 25k images exists for each class and a total of only 4 classes exist.

Comment: the vgg16 has millions of weights. 100k images is not enough to fully train it. If you cant add more augmentation maybe only train the last few layers of the model: `new_model.trainable = False` to freeze the whole model and:

`for layer in new_model.layers[-3:]:    layer.trainable = True` to only train the last 3 layers

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, this is partially true. Overfitting may come from a lack of data, or may come from other sources. I have tried it but lowering the number of trainable parameters from 14M to 3M (equivalent to what you suggested) has yet to succeed. Even at 200k trainable parameters, overfitting occurs, which sounds peculiar.

Comment: I think 100k images is plenty to avoid overfitting on VGG - esp. if you're going to replace the last classifier layer with your own for 4 classes. Please keep in mind that you can also replace the average pooling layer with a smaller output size. I think trying stronger data augmentations should definitely help. Based on your setup, you may need to decide if spatial and/or color based augmentations are appropriate for your task at hand.